# How to set limit of how many movies to display based on movie id 1-20

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, api, react-native

I am using react native to build a movies app with the moviedb api. I have a question which is how to set it that it will display movies with ids or indexes from 1-20? So either 10 or 20 movies to display on screen. Or get at least more than one movie back from the api call. I know how to get one movie which the docs states clearly. I get the movie posseiden because I have I have called the movie number in the api call which is 551. I have went through their api docs and tried to see if there are any api limit params and also searched the forums but other people didnt have the same questions. Just wondering if anyone knows how to do this. Thanks

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList} from "react-native";
import axios from "axios";

const HomeScreen =()=> {
    const API_KEY1="blah blah";
    const API_KEY2="blah blah";
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);


    useEffect(()=> {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/551?api_key=${API_KEY2}`);
            setMovies([response.data]);
            console.log("RESPONSEEEEEEDATAAAA", response.data);
            console.log("MOVIESSSS", movies)
        }

        fetchData();

    }, [])


    return(
        <View style={styles.screen}>
            <FlatList data={movies} renderItem={({item})=> {
                return <Text>{[item.original_title]}</Text>
            }}/>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent:"center",
        alignItems:"center"
    }
})

export default HomeScreen;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong API method for what you are trying to do.The POST to movie is specifically for getting details about an individual movie. You should be using the search featureto find specific movies or to list movies look at the API for posts such as get-popular-movies:

1. https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-popular-movies
2. https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/search/search-movies

Go down to finding data on this page to see different ways to find data: https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the wrong API endpoint. 
Under https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/ you can do:

- GET latest
- GET now playing
- GET popular
- GET top rated
- GET upcoming

Here is what you need to read on the link above

[image]